# Which type of service in Android will use more system resources

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

Would it be better to have a service that is continually running a timer and executing a task every five seconds.  Or would it be more efficient to have an alarm manager starting the service every five seconds? How about every second?  I'm interested to hear your responses.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the AlarmManager documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html), it's only for cases where you want to run at a specific time. For what you're talking about, you'll want to use a Handler, with postDelayed().

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended
>   for cases where you want to have your
>   application code run at a specific
>   time, even if your application is not
>   currently running. For normal timing
>   operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it
>   is easier and much more efficient to
>   use Handler.